# OpenCV bitwise not operator returns nan for black pixels

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to apply the OpenCV `not` bitwise operator to binary images.
I have generated a two-dimensional black image as follows:
`black = np.zeros((400, 400))`.
But when applying `cv2.bitwise_not` to it, all zeros are replaced with `nan`. Can someone explain this behaviour and tell me how to fix it?

I also generated a white image using the below code, but `bitwise_not` replaces pixels with the value -4:

```
white = np.zeros((400, 400))
white[:, :] = 255
```

While I was expecting it to replace 255's with 0's.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unless you specify the type, numpy generates floating point arrays. Try specifying an 8-but image. numpy.uint8 if I correcly Remember. Check numpy docs!

Comment: @matteonunziati is right, if you check documentation (eg https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga0002cf8b418479f4cb49a75442baee2f) it says that "in case of a floating-point input array, its machine-specific bit representation (usually IEEE754-compliant) is used for the operation"

Answer (score 0):

As Matteo pointed out in the comments, the problem comes from the data type used when generating the image. You would have to specify `dtype=np.uint8`.

Answer (score 0):

```
white = np.zeros((400, 400))
white = 255 * white
inverse_white = 255 - white
```

Rather than replacing its better to use the convention of image pixels (0,255). Alternatively to get a inverse mask you can subtract it by 1. as its stored in 8 bit.

```
white = np.zeros((400, 400))
inverse_white = 1. - white
```